# Is there a Chrome API to access responsive mode to resize to custom width and height?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, responsive

Is there any chrome API to access inspect mode and resize to custom width and height. I am developing a screenshot taking chrome extension for multiple devices but I am having hard  time to resize the window. So any help regarding the responsive mode using chrome API will be so helpful and appreciated. Thank you.

[Image:Responsive mode in Developer Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXGLD.jpg)

Comment: Extensions can use chrome.debugger to send setDeviceMetricsOverride, look for examples.